# Generar números aleatorios e insertarlos en un array

Tags: php

¿Cómo puedo generar un número aleatorio e insertarlos en los campos 'notas' del siguiente array?

```
$persona1= [
    'nombre' => 'persona1',
    'notas' => []
];

$persona2= [
    'nombre' => 'persona2',
    'notas' => []
];

$persona3= [
    'nombre' => 'persona3',
    'notas' => []
];

$datos=[$persona1,$persona2,$persona3];
$_SESSION['datos'] = $datos;
```

Comment: ¿A qué array te refieres? (Hay un array `$datos` y varios arrays de personas).... ¿Desde dónde quieres insertarlos? ¿Qué has investigado/intentado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP provee multiples funciones para generar números pseudo-aleatorios, entre ellas [`rand()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.rand.php), [`random_int()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.random-int.php) (PHP7), [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mt-rand.php).

Puedes utilizar cualquiera de ellas, aun que `random_int()` es la opción mas fiable.

Puedes rellenar el array recorriendolo con un bucle, por ejemplo:

```
$persona1= [
    'nombre' => 'persona1',
    'notas' => []
];

$persona2= [
    'nombre' => 'persona2',
    'notas' => []
];

$persona3= [
    'nombre' => 'persona3',
    'notas' => []
];

$datos=[$persona1, $persona2, $persona3];

// rango 0-10 sin decimales
foreach ($datos as $key => $value) {
    $datos[$key]['notas'] = random_int(0, 10);
}

print_r($datos);
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nombre] => persona1
            [notas] => 7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [nombre] => persona2
            [notas] => 9
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [nombre] => persona3
            [notas] => 5
        )
)
```

Si por algun motivo requieres que los números sean de tipo float puedes hacer algo así por ejemplo para 2 decimales del entre el rango 0-10:

```
foreach ($datos as $key => $value) {
    $datos[$key]['notas'] = random_int(0, 1000)/100;
}
```

Resultado ejemplo:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nombre] => persona1
            [notas] => 4.17
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [nombre] => persona2
            [notas] => 8
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [nombre] => persona3
            [notas] => 1.37
        )
)
```

Otra opción podría ser la propuesta en la documentación de `mt_getrandmax()`

Ejemplo:

```
function randomFloat($min = 0, $max = 1) {
    return $min + mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax() * ($max - $min);
}


foreach ($datos as $key => $value) {
    $datos[$key]['notas'] = randomFloat(0, 10);
}

print_r($datos);
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nombre] => persona1
            [notas] => 6.5754064016861
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [nombre] => persona2
            [notas] => 6.3999850286171
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [nombre] => persona3
            [notas] => 7.8233306705129
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función **rand()** de **PHP**.

```
$persona1= [
   'nombre' => 'persona1',
   'notas' => rand(1, 15)
];

$persona2= [
   'nombre' => 'persona2',
   'notas' => rand(1, 15)
];

$persona3= [
   'nombre' => 'persona3',
   'notas' => rand(1, 15)
];

$datos=[$persona1,$persona2,$persona3];
$_SESSION['datos'] = $datos;
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la función [mt_rand](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mt-rand.php). Es más rápida que rand y produce un número "más aleatorio" que su compañera.

El manejo es muy sencillo. Esta función recibe dos argumentos, que son simplemente los valores mínimo y máximo entre los cuales se generará ese número aleatorio (ambos incluidos). Osea, en el caso de las notas podrías hacer:

```
$persona1= [
    'nombre' => 'persona1',
    'notas' => mt_rand(0,10)
];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$numeroAleatorio = rand(0, 10);
        $persona1= [
                    'nombre' => 'persona1',
                    'notas' => []
                    ];
        $persona1['notas']=$numeroAleatorio;
        echo $persona1['notas'];
```

Mira a ver si te sirve así.
Un saludo.

Comment: Pero pueden ser más personas. Imagino que lo que se busca es algo automatizado. De todos modos la pregunta no es clara.

Comment: Le ayudo pero no le hago sus ejercicios, eso que lo automatice el. Aun asi solo seria insertar un foreach y que recorra.

Comment: @doyaguezz por favor agregue una descripción a su código, lee: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Para organizar el código, selecciona el código y presiona [ctrl] + [k]. Mira [esta y otras funcionalidades para formatear lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) también ese mucha ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: no es solo colocar código y ya, detente a leer [answer] debes explicar lo que colocas}